# GoogleMapsUtils Framework wrapped in Cocoapods Build error on Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, frameworks, cocoapods

I'm trying to develop a Cocoapods library that wraps the Google Maps Utils for iOS in a Objective C Projects. I succeded building and passing the lint and link validation, but when I execute the project in a Xcode I get bulding error.

```
'GoogleMaps/GMSAddress.h' file not found
```

I imported the Google Maps manualy and trying to use this pod:
https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils

Here is podspec file

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.name             = 'Core'
s.version          = '0.1.0'
s.summary          = 'Core. Core for APPS. Maps System. More.'

s.description      = <<-DESC
Core is the heart of all the APPS instances and APPS.
Includes all the major assets and the resources for optimize all the     system.
Anyway the wind blows.
DESC

s.homepage         = ''
# s.screenshots    = 'www.example.com/screenshots_1', 
'www.example.com/screenshots_2'
s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
s.author           = { 'Moblie Department' => 'ios-dev@core.com' }
s.source           = { :git => 'https://mycore.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }

s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'
s.requires_arc = true
s.source_files = 'SkitudeCore/Classes/**/*.{h,m}',
                'StaticLibraries/**/*.h'

#s.compiler_flags = '-fno-modules'

s.frameworks = 'CoreData','SystemConfiguration', 'Accelerate', 'CoreGraphics', 'CoreLocation', 'CoreText', 'GLKit', 'ImageIO', 'OpenGLES', 'QuartzCore', 'UIKit', 'AdSupport', "GoogleMaps", "GoogleMapsBase", "GoogleMapsCore"
s.vendored_frameworks   = 'StaticLibraries/GoogleMaps.framework', 'StaticLibraries/GoogleMapsBase.framework', 'StaticLibraries/GoogleMapsCore.framework'
s.xcconfig = {'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => ' -ObjC -lc++', 'CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES' => 'YES', 'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2'}
s.library = 'z', 'c++', 'xml2'

s.resource_bundles = {
'SkitudeCore' => ['SkitudeCore/Assets/**/*.{png,jpg,xib,strings}'],
'GoogleMapsBundle' => ['StaticLibraries/GoogleMaps.bundle/**/*.{png,jpg,xib,strings}']
}

s.public_header_files ='StaticLibraries/GoogleMapsCore.framework/**/*.h',
'StaticLibraries/GoogleMapsBase.framework/**/*.h',
'StaticLibraries/GoogleMaps.framework/**/*.h'


s.dependency 'NSHash', '~> 1.1'
s.dependency 'sqlite3'

end
```

And my podfile

```
use_frameworks!
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false
platform :ios, '9.0'
target 'SkitudeCore_Example' do
  pod 'SkitudeCore', :path => '../'
   target 'SkitudeCore_Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end
```